# How to generate different dictionaries depending of length of keys from another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary named `k`. As you may see, within the dictionary I have tuples of items as keys and integers as its values. It can be seen that the keys have different lengths. What I want to do is to separate the elements from this dictionary into different dictionaries based on the length of its keys.

For example:

- The first 3 elements (milk, beer and umbrella) must be in a dictionary named `dic1`.
- The next 10 elements must be in a a dictionary named `dic2` since the length of its keys is equal to 2.
- And the last 4 elements must be in a a dictionary named `dic3` since the length of its keys is equal to 3.

[image]

I am trying to use the following code to solve the problem previously explained.

```
# base name
nombre = 'dic'
for key in original_dictionary:
    for i in range(1, 6):
        # generate names of the dictionaries
        name = nombre + str(i)
        # create empty dictionaries (based on the name assigned above)
        name = {}

        # update elements within the dictionary
        if len(key) == i:
            name.update(key, original_dictionary[key])
```

However I am having this error:

```
TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

I'm not really sure about how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dictionary comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

Take following dict for example:

```
In [260]: k = {('milk',):2, ('beer',):5, ('umbrella',):8, ('diaper', 'milk'):1, ('diaper', 'bread'):2, ('diaper', 'milk', 'bread'):1, ('diaper', 'milk', 'beer'): 1}

In [270]: d1 = {key:v for key, v in k.items() if len(key) == 1}

In [271]: d2 = {key:v for key, v in k.items() if len(key) == 2}

In [272]: d3 = {key:v for key, v in k.items() if len(key) == 3}

In [273]: d1
Out[273]: {('milk',): 2, ('beer',): 5, ('umbrella',): 8}

In [274]: d2
Out[274]: {('diaper', 'milk'): 1, ('diaper', 'bread'): 2}

In [275]: d3
Out[275]: {('diaper', 'milk', 'bread'): 1, ('diaper', 'milk', 'beer'): 1}
```

Comment: It is my expected output, however, I'm still trying to get it done in a for-loop.

Comment: `for` loops are slower compared to `dict comprehensions`. Why do you need that?

Comment: I am just trying to get it done 'automatically' but I'm also trying to implement your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .update, assign:

```
nombre = 'dic'
for key in original_dictionary:
    for i in range(1, 6):
        name = nombre + str(i)
        name = {}
        if len(key) == i:
            name[key] = original_dictionary[key]
```

Comment: dont think this would work as every time you go to a new key, you overwrite the existing dictionary (`name`)that you have previously made

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work. I tried printing dic1 and I got this error: 'NameError: name 'dic1' is not defined' for if I try to print *name* I get this output: {('cheese', 'detergent', 'beer', 'umbrella', 'water'): 1}

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2 dictionaries it makes sense to put them into list:

```
d = {('milk',):2, ('beer',):5,
     ('umbrella',):8,
     ('diaper', 'milk'):1,
     ('diaper', 'bread'):2,
     ('diaper', 'milk', 'bread'):1,
     ('diaper', 'milk', 'beer'): 1}

dcts = [{} for i in range(max(map(len, d)))] # create a list with empty dicts
for k, v in d.items(): # iterate over key-value pairs
  dct = dcts[len(k)-1] # get the right dict
  dct[k] = v # assign key-value pair to this dict
```

Result:

```
[{('beer',): 5, ('milk',): 2, ('umbrella',): 8},
 {('diaper', 'bread'): 2, ('diaper', 'milk'): 1},
 {('diaper', 'milk', 'beer'): 1, ('diaper', 'milk', 'bread'): 1}]
```